# Select values by one parameter and complete table with other

Tags: mysql, sql

Really hard to explain my problem in the title.
Basically I have a table of translations with multiple languages in it which looks like this

```
+---------------+----------------------------------+----------+
| name          | translation                      | language |
+---------------+----------------------------------+----------+
| translation_1 | This is text for translation n.1 | en       |
+---------------+----------------------------------+----------+
| translation_2 | This is text for translation n.2 | en       |
+---------------+----------------------------------+----------+
| translation_3 | This is text for translation n.2 | en       |
+---------------+----------------------------------+----------+
| translation_2 | Toto je text pre preklad č.2     | sk       |
+---------------+----------------------------------+----------+
```

Now I need to fetch translations with language 'sk' but I can't be sure there always will be all translations for all languages so what I want to achieve is to fetch everything with language 'sk' and complete with translations with language 'en' (which will be default language and always will have all translations).

This should be result

```
+---------------+----------------------------------+----------+
| name          | translation                      | language |
+---------------+----------------------------------+----------+
| translation_1 | This is text for translation n.1 | en       |
+---------------+----------------------------------+----------+
| translation_2 | Toto je text pre preklad č.2     | sk       |
+---------------+----------------------------------+----------+
| translation_3 | This is text for translation n.2 | en       |
+---------------+----------------------------------+----------+
```

Thanks for advice!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Considering that each translation exists for "en", you can do

```
SELECT
  en.name,
  IFNULL(sk.translation, en.translation) AS translation,
  IFNULL(sk.language, en.language) AS language
FROM translation AS en
  LEFT JOIN translation AS sk ON en.name = sk.name AND sk.language = "sk"
WHERE en.language = "en"
```

You select all English translations and do a left join with the Swedish translations. For the translation and language column, you state *prefer the Swedish, but otherwise English*.

Answer (score 0):

You can use variables to simulate `ROW_NUMBER()` window function available in other RDBMS:

```
SELECT name, translation, language
FROM (
  SELECT translation, language,
         @row_number:= CASE WHEN @name = name THEN @row_number+1
                            ELSE 1
                       END AS row_number,
         @name:=name AS name              
  FROM translations
  ORDER BY name, CASE WHEN language = 'sk' THEN 1
                      WHEN language = 'en' THEN 2
                      ELSE 3
                 END ) t
WHERE row_number = 1                 
ORDER BY name
```

`@row_number` is being reset each time a new `name` is encountered. Within each `name` partition, a value of `@row_number = 1` points to an `sk` translation if available, otherwise to an `en` translation.

[**SQL Fiddle Demo**](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/9de3f/1)